# Downloading QGIS Desktop 2.6.1

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

https://chocolatey.org/packages/QGIS/2.6.1#individual.

I used the above link to download QGIS 2.6.1 but in this QGIS 2.6.1 Desktop is no where to be seen after installation.

Please suggest.

Comment: Why not using the official QGIS download page and why not using the last version (2.6 is rather old, last is 3.15) see https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html (there is an "All Releases" tab for old version)

Comment: chocolatey uses the official QGIS installers, but yes 2.6 is ancient